# why Python taking so much memory?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I am working on a text file that is 467KB in size. I have this code.

```
@profile
def parse_sentences(paragraph):
    all_sentences_paragraph = {}
    nlp.max_length = len(paragraph['text'])
    doc = nlp(paragraph['text'])
    allSentences = []
    tempSentences = list(doc.sents)
    allSentences = list(process_sentence(tempSentences))
    all_sentences_paragraph[paragraph['pid']] = allSentences
    paragraph['text'] = ""
    return paragraph['pid'], allSentences


@profile
def process_sentence(tempSentences):
    for sentence in tempSentences:
        tempSentenceJson = {
            "text": "",
            "tags": {},
        }
        if sentence:
            tempSentenceJson['text'] = str(sentence)
            tempSentenceJson['sid'] = uuid.uuid4().hex
            yield tempSentenceJson
        else:
            tempSentenceJson['sid'] = uuid.uuid4().hex
            yield tempSentenceJson
```

This line gets called 8561 times.

```
allSentences = list(process_sentence(tempSentences))
```

Now here is a profile summary of this function.

[image]

[image]

Now my question is, why is it taking so much space for a file of 467KB. How I can solve this issue?

Comment: But the memory usage stays at 96.1mb? Which seems reasonable... It's like the increment is summed by the number of times or something. Are you monitoring the memory usage of the process using something else?

Comment: No, I am using this memory profiler only. But if I give it a file with 400+mb, Python takes 3gb+ memory which I can see from the system monitor too. I have a 20GB ram, with a file of 1GB size, python uses 10GB ram with a full 2GB swap. Why is that?

Comment: Because, you aren't processing raw text, python objects are large, and everything is an object. dicts are a very inefficient way of doing this. You could probably stick with using dicts if you process everything one at a time instead of making a giant list.

Comment: Is there any solution? I can't leave dicts because I am converting my raw text file into a json.